# Ошибка при использовании VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Часто при использовании VSCode вылетает ошибка. Загуглить не смог. Обычно просто нажимаю прервать, если нажму пропустить, будут другие ошибки. Как убрать эту ошибку?
[image: скрин ошибки]

Comment: Полностью сносить и переустанавливать пробовали?

Comment: Запускаться от имени администратора (используйте эту рекомендацию на свой страх и риск)

Comment: странная ошибка. Она похожа на ошибку при установке VSC не от имени администратора. Кстати, не все знают, что для винды у VSC есть два инсталлятора: на странице https://code.visualstudio.com/download есть user installer и system installer. Так вот, user installer всю инсталляцию пихает в профайл пользователя, а это не всегда удобно. Я бы воспользовался system installer и запустил инсталляцию от имени администратора (правой кнопкой, выполнить с правами администратора - как то так)

Comment: @S.H. Переустановил системной установкой от администратора, ошибки пропали. Спасиб.